# React: Manage State of Menu Items and Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to React. I have written a simple React application using Semantic UI, with two menu items, each corresponding to a specific page. I'm not sure how to make each page have its own state, and remember it when navigating the menu.

In index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Main />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In Main.jsx:

```
export default class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        activePageId: 1
    };

    handleSelectPage = (e, { id: selectedPageId }) => {
        this.setState({ activePageId: selectedPageId })
    }

    getActivePage() {
        return (
            <Page id={this.state.activePageId} />
        )
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Grid divided padded >
                <Grid.Column width={2}>
                    <Menu vertical inverted pointing fluid>
                        <Menu.Item
                            id={1}
                            name='Page 1'
                            active={this.state.activePageId === 1}
                            onClick={this.handleSelectPage}
                            key={1}
                        />
                        <Menu.Item
                            id={2}
                            name='Page 2'
                            active={this.state.activePageId === 2}
                            onClick={this.handleSelectPage}
                            key={2}
                        />
                    </Menu>
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column width={14}>
                    {this.getActivePage()}
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}
```

Finally, in Page.jsx:

```
export default class Page extends Component {
    state = {
        counter: 0
    };

    increaseCounter = (e) => {
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Header>Page {this.props.id}</Header>
                {this.state.counter}
                <Button primary content='+' onClick={this.increaseCounter}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out:

1. The page `id` is passed in the props when creating a `Page` component in `getActivePage()`. So, that changes every time I navigate the menu. However, the `counter` is in the state of the `Page`. That does not change as I navigate the menu. Am I correct to assume there is only one instance of a `Page`, which is re-rendered when the props (in this case `id`) change?
2. It seems like the only way to have a separate counter for each page is to have some sort global state (in a global object) and read from that when rendering a `Page`. This would mean, however, that I need to call `this.forceUpdate` inside `Page.increaseCounter` to re-render the page without re-clicking the menu item. Is that the React way to go?
3. I'm also thinking about using routing. But, from my preliminary experiments, it seems that, compared to the current scenario, a new `Page` would be created for each route (is this right?) with its own state. However, that state gets wiped out when navigating between routes, so I still need to keep a global state object and use `forceUpdates` or so. Any ideas here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the counter state inside your Main.jsx component, and then pass the counter state as props to Page.jsx. I recommend you to use functional components and useState hook. Here you can see an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bardeen-8w58z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: But how would I proceed if I wanted to modify a Page's counter within the page itself? Like if I had a button in each page to increase _its own_ counter. Would I, in fact, increase the counter from props? If I do so, the current page will not re-render...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to create a counter for every page? In this case, there will be two counters, one for each page?

Comment: I guess you want something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bardeen-8w58z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! But is this good practice? If every page needs its own state, it is the main component that needs to store a separate state for each page. What then is the point of each page having a state?

Comment: For bigger applications, you may want to use a different state manager, such as Redux. In this case, if you want to store your state globally and use it anywhere, consider using React Context. As I understood, you wanted to have state on every page, and there is nothing wrong with it. Here on main component we are handling state for page ids only, and on Page.js we are handling the counters. If you need help with setting Redux or Context, let me know.